# Phonegap Click issue in Nexus Jellybean phone

Tags: android, cordova, dom-events, phonegap

I am developing an Android application using Phonegap. In Google Nexus phone, when I click once, it takes the click twice means the function I am calling will be executed twice.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

call the function on your button or href like this:

```
$('#buttonID').off("click").on("click", function () {

});
```